# how to access table values by [rowno][columnno] in stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Below is my stored procedure code:

```
CREATE TYPE my_table AS TABLE (
  rowID int,
  fromTable varchar(40),
  tableRow int,
  fromRange varchar(10),
  toRange int
)

USE TestDB;
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('table_parameter_sample_proc') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROCEDURE table_parameter_sample_proc;
go 
CREATE PROCEDURE table_parameter_sample_proc (
@datasource my_table READONLY)
AS

SELECT
  rowID,fromTable,tableRow,fromRange,toRange
FROM @datasource
GO
```

it's working fine. This is how i am calling it:

```
DECLARE @datasource AS my_table
INSERT @datasource (rowID, fromTable,tableRow,fromRange,toRange)
VALUES
  (1, 'TableA',2,'3',5),
  (2, 'TableB',3,'y',null),
  (3, 'TableC',4,'5',10)
EXEC table_parameter_sample_proc @datasource
```

When I call stored procedure It returns whole table, but I need to access value individually, for example i need the value 'tableA' only (table[row][column]). when i write

```
SELECT fromTable[0] FROM @datasource
```

It gives me all the values of column fromTable and fromTable[0][0] doesn't work.
What is the solution for this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: your SP will not work because you pass table-name dynamic and you haven't use dynamic expression and exec() statement

Comment: above code i have written here is working fine.

Comment: You are trying to select like cells in Excel? And how SQL Server suppose to know what row is second f.e. in `TableA`?